# socket.io websocket client sends but does not receive Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, websocket, ionic5

I implemented a Node server and an Angular client (actually Ionic). What I do is send a message from Ionic to Node, and it receives it correctly, but afterwards the server should respond to me but I don't receive any response.

This is the client:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as socketIo from 'socket.io-client'
import { Observable, subscribeOn } from 'rxjs';

const backendUri = "http://localhost:3000";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketIoService {

private clientSocket: socketIo.Socket
constructor() { 
this.clientSocket = socketIo.connect(backendUri)
}

listenToServer(topic: string): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable((subscribe) => {
    this.clientSocket.on(topic, (data) => {
      subscribe.next(data);
      console.log(data)
    });
  });
}

emitToServer(topic: string, data: string){
  this.clientSocket.emit(topic,data)
}
```

}

And I use it in here

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SocketIoService } from './socket-io.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
  export class AppComponent {
    public appPages = [
      { title: 'Corsa', url: '/fist-page', icon: 'time' },
      { title: 'Impostazioni Box', url: '/settings', icon: 'settings' },
    ];
    public labels = ['Label'];

 topic: string = "myTopic"

 constructor(private socketServices: SocketIoService) {
   this.socketServices.listenToServer(this.topic).subscribe((create) => { 
  console.log(create); console.log("Client in ascolto") });
   this.createInfo()
 }

 createInfo(){
    this.socketServices.emitToServer(this.topic,"test")
  }

}
```

This is the Node server:

```
    var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var connection = require("./connection.js")
var socket = require("socket.io")

var server = app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
})

var socketIo = socket(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  }
});

socketIo.on('connection', (socket) => {

    console.log("Connection has been created with: " + socket.id);

    socket.on(connection.topic2, (data) => {
        socketIo.sockets.emit(connection.topic2, data)
    });

    socket.on(connection.topic1, (newData) => {
        socketIo.sockets.emit(connection.topic1, newData)
        console.log("Inviati i dati: " + newData)
    });

})
```

This is my simple topic:

```
module.exports = {
    topic1: 'myTopic',
    topic2: 'myTopic2'
}
```